# How to change the audio output from speaker phone to earpiece in flutter android?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using `flutter_webrtc` package for audio call functionality of my app and by default the audio output is on speakerphone how can I change the speaker phone to earpiece in flutter.

By analysing the code I used this method which is method in `RTCVideoRenderer` class called `audioOutput` but it throws `unImplementedError`.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `audioOutput` method in the `RTCVideoRenderer` class like this

android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

```
/// get all media devices
final devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

/// get all audio output device
List<MediaDeviceInfo> get audioOutputs => devices.where((device) => device.kind == 'audiooutput').toList(); 

/// find speaker device
 MediaDeviceInfo? get _outputSpeaker => audioOutputs.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element.deviceId == "speaker"); 

/// and finally switch audio output device
/// localvideo is RTCVideoRenderer class  of flutter_webrtc package (local video)
await localVideo?.audioOutput(_outputSpeaker!.deviceId);
```

Comment: It's not possible, due to in source code `enableSpeakerphone()` is not implemented.
@hamere did you solve this?

Comment: really ?? i used flutter_webrtc at version 0.7.1 and `getAudioTracks`  you can get mediaStreamTrack and mediastreamtraks have methood enableSpeakerphone(), ```bool localToSpeakerPhone(bool mute) {
    if (_localStream?.getAudioTracks().isNotEmpty ?? false)
      _localStream?.getAudioTracks().first.enableSpeakerphone(mute);
    return mute;
  }``` my code to switch between speaker and earpiece @Fikret

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was referring to interface https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc/blob/master/lib/src/interface/media_stream_track.dart#L99
According to code we can use `WebRTC.invokeMethod(
      'enableSpeakerphone',
      <String, dynamic>{'trackId': _trackId, 'enable': true/false},
    )`

Comment: np, now u can give me a  badge :D @Fikret

Comment: OK :) 
But actually i solved it with just adding ` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />` to manifest file only... don't know regard iOS, no device next to me.

Comment: hi, please i having this same issue and i added the user permission, but i dont know where i will use this method    "currentRender.srcObject?.getAudioTracks()[trackIndex].enableSpeakerphone(boolean);"...  thanks